# SYS.DBMS_AQ Grant causes ORA-00990

Tags: oracle11g, oracle11gr2

When trying to grant SYS.DBMS_AQ to user, Oracle claims the package is missing or invalid. ORA-00990. Any idea why Oracle DB does not have this package? 11.2.0.1 is the version for the OracleDB.

Comment: can you please post the exact ddl you ran?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ORA-00990` means the grant DDL wasn't right, not that the package is invalid. please check the DDL syntax you used. It should be of the form:

```
grant execute on dbms_aq to SCHEMANAME;
```

substituting `SCHEMANAME` for your real user.